# Rails MS SQL query starting at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I have a rails app querying a MS SQL DB, it is checking to see if one column is false, but I realistically only need to check in the last 1000 records (there are just over 900,000 records).

It takes a long time to check over everything every time, so is there a way to limit it to only check the last 1000 for this column? I've tried using @object.find_each, but that checks 1000 at a time, but goes through the whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather easy; all you have to do is to use `YourModel.order('id desc').limit(1000).where('your_column = false')`, which would generate the query to search through your last thousand rows.

Comment: Worked a treat - thanks.
For the record, i have an approval page which only shows entries that have 'approved' that is false. In the controller I set the 'approved' method to have what you suggested, watching the console it only checked the 1000 rows desc. Very quick result now.